# javascript laravel - call a function when the checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have following function in my onRender function, which will be called when the findall checkbox 
is clicked.

```
this.$el.find('.findall').on('click', function(e) { ...  });
```

I want to know how can I write a function simillar to above which should be called if the checkbox is checked. (by default I am checking this checkbox, but the above function will be called only when I click that box, but I need something that will called based on the checkbox status).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do different actions depending on whether an item is checked or not:

```
this.$el.find('.findall').each(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        // do action for checked
    } else {
        // do action for not checked
    }
});
```

If you want to do actions only on each checked checkbox:

```
this.$el.find('.findall :checked').each(function () {
        // do action for checked
});
```

Or if you want to do it on page load:

```
$(function () {
    $('.findall').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            // do action for a checked checkbox
        } else {
            // do action for an unchecked checkbox
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
this.$el.find('.findall').on('change', function(e)
{
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        // Do your job here...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this will be called when there is change. I want this function to be called onload of that checkbox.. This function should be called when the checkbox is displayed without requiring any change or click.

Comment: Then use `$(document).ready(...)` and use `$('.findall :checked')`.